# Sysprep inaccessible machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, disk-image, sysprep

I need to move a known working Windows 7 OS from one machine to another.  Problem is, the source machine is not bootable due to hardware failure, but the OS and data are fine. Due to hardware incompatibilities between the source and target how would it be possible to sysprep (or solve HAL incompatibilities some other way) the source OS without booting to windows on the original system.  (Also without replacing broken hardware.)

Thank you!

Here are some solutions I know of that handle imaging but NOT HAL without sysprepping (as far as I know):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)

[Norton Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/themes/theme.jsp?themeid=ghost)

[FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/)

[WDS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831764.aspx)

Comment: I normally use `Acronis True Image` or something like that supports restoring the image to new hardware.  There are other alternative solutions most are paid software though.

Comment: True Image takes care of new hardware incompatibilities?  Ill take a look at that.  Know of any open source solutions?

Comment: I was nice enough to even provide you with an example.  I am not going recommend additionally software, I didn't even recommend `Acronis` technically, just used it as an example.

Comment: No problem. It is appreciated.  I guess I could have been more specific and mentioned software I do know of that can take images but NOT handle HAL without sysprep.

Answer (score 1):

Another consideration that may be worth exploring is to restore the image to a virtual machine. The virtual environment will rarely have an issue booting from the image.